# Impossible to get Intel Wi-Fi adapter recognised on Ubuntu 18.04 without Ethernet or CD-ROM drive

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, dell, iwlwifi, ubuntu-drivers

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 on a new Dell Precision 5540, and I am getting the "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" message. This is a dual-boot installation, alongside Windows 10, and the Wi-Fi connection in the latter works fine (so no hardware problem). In the last couple of days, I have read through about 50 different posts suggesting a variety of solutions: so far, these have been either not relevant or not worked.

My particular problem is that the laptop has neither a CD-ROM drive nor an ethernet port (so no updates easily downloadable without Wi-Fi).  Also, the Network controller [0280] is 'Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)'. I believe that the driver for this should be automatically installed. The installation was done from the iso image mounted on a USB drive, both with secure boot enabled and third-party software installation not selected, and with secure boot disabled and the third-party option selected.

After installation, I have tried the Software & Updates utility with the "Installable from CD-ROM/DVD" option selected and the iso image of the installer mounted locally as a virtual drive.  In this case the Additional Drivers tab shows "No additional drivers available" and "No proprietary drivers are in use" - which may be because the Intel adapter should be supported in the Canonical software.  I tried the suggestion to purge bcmwl-kernel-source, but the package was not installed (again, probably because it was not needed).

The other approach that I tried was using a USB3/Ethernet adapter to connect to a cable.  Unfortunately, devices like this all require drivers to be installed - usually, of course, downloaded from the Internet. By downloading in Windows and then transferring to Ubuntu, I found that the installation files required building, but the "make" command didn't work, because "make" was not installed (and probably a lot more from build-essential that cannot be accessed without, yes - an Internet connection!).

I am beginning to feel like a rat trapped in a cage. Any helpful suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Many USB3/Ethernet adapters don't need any drivers. Do you have access to a USB wifi dongle?

Comment: Do you have a recommendation?  The last one I got did not explain on the box that it needed a driver installed.

Comment: See https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-Foldable-Gigabit-Ethernet-Compatible/dp/B00YUU3KC6/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2CE4S4G651691&keywords=tp-link+usb+3.0+to+gigabit+ethernet+adapter&qid=1580843356&refinements=p_89%3ATP-Link&rnid=2528832011&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&sprefix=tp-link+usb+ethernet+adapter%2Caps%2C258&sr=8-1 and it's on sale for $9.99

Comment: Thanks heynnema.  I went out and got a UNI USB-C to Ethernet Adapter and that did the job.  The software updater then quickly fixed the Wi-Fi problem.  Time for Canonical to update their version of the 18.04 installer download I would have thought.  These wireless, disk-less laptops are getting quite common now.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is that there are some wireless adapters that are compatible with Linux without needing a driver loaded (see the comments).  It is just that the manufacturers descriptions are rarely explicit about this. I would avoid buying anything that doesn't say "Linux" and/or is in a box big enough to contain a disk.